# Merge duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Customer table which contains an ID and Email field.  I've written the following query to return all duplicate Customers with the same Email:

```
SELECT ID, Email 
FROM Customer a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  1
              FROM Customer b
              WHERE a.Email = b.Email
              GROUP BY Email
              HAVING COUNT(Email) = 2)
ORDER BY Email
```

This is returning records that look like the following:

```
ID    Email
1     a@hotmail.com
2     a@hotmail.com
3     b@gmail.com
4     b@gmail.com
```

While this works, I actually need the data in the following format:

```
ID1    Email1          ID2    Email2
1      a@hotmail.com   2      a@hotmail.com
3      b@gmail.com     4      b@gmail.com
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, Email, MAX(ID) ID2, Email AS EMAIL2
FROM Customer GROUP BY Email
```

if you want HAVING COUNT(Email) = 2, it will be like this

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, Email, MAX(ID) ID2, Email AS EMAIL2
FROM Customer GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(Email) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Hong.  My situation is specific for 2 duplicates as if there are matches of 3 or more than they are being handled differently.  All the replies here seem to work, but I like the simplicity of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation . . . assuming you have at most two emails:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then id end) as id_1,
       email as email_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then id end) as id_2,
       email as email_2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by id) as seqnum
      from t
      ) t
group by email;
```

Actually, why not just do:

```
select email, count(*) as num_dups, min(id) as id_1,
       (case when count(*) > 1 then max(id) end) as id_2
from t
group by email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout assumes that you can only have a total of 2 duplicates.

Maybe list the IDs instead like below?

```
declare @Duplicates table (Email varchar(50), Customers varchar(100))
insert @Duplicates select Email, '' from Customer group by Email having count(*) > 1

UPDATE d
SET
    Customers= STUFF((  SELECT ','+ cast(ID as varchar(10)) 
                        FROM Customer c
                        WHERE c.Email = d.Email            
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM @Duplicates AS d 

select * from @Duplicates 
order by Email
```